# mysqli_real_escape_string() for entire $_POST array in php

Tags: php, post, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I have `$_POST` with 20 keys. I want to apply `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for the entire `$_POST` array. So, should I apply `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to all 20 keys separately? Or is there any loop or any specific function available for it?

My Post array is like the example below:

```
$_POST =array(
      "A1"=>'xxxxxxxx',
      "A2"=>'xxxxxxxx',
      ........
      ........
      ........
      ..........
      .........
      .........
      "A20"=> 'xxxxxxxxx'
);
```

Comment: **STOP!!** "I want to apply mysqli_real_escape_string() for entire $_POST array" — That is a bad solution to pretty much any problem. Data should be escaped at **the last moment** before being used for whatever it is being used for (i.e. just before being inserted into SQL not just after it comes out of HTTP). What's more, mysqli_real_escape_string should be avoided in favour of bound variables / prepared statements.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
$escaped = array_map(function($var) use ($mysqli){
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $var);
},$_POST);
```

Comment: [*`mysqli_real_escape_string()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli*…](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973202/476)

Comment: The fixed version now doesn't work because [`$mysqli` is not in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/476).

Comment: so fixed that too.

Comment: It worked in one page, but didn't in another. `mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in...`